# Is there a better library than BouncyCastle?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, encryption

Is there a better free open source library than `BouncyCastel` that's managed using `.Net` , and it includes `Cast5,Blowfish,DH and SRP` ciphers and also includes the 4 modes `CBC, CFB, OFB, and ECB`?

Comment: better? Regarding which criteria?

Comment: @nulltoken well BouncyCastel not uses shift register in cipher modes , aslo it has the old SRP cipher I believe tho!

Comment: You need to ask which is better for what *you* are trying to do. There are several crypto libraries for .net, and each has its own weaknesses. Depending on what you need `Mono.Security` might be a match, but their SSL implementation is pretty poor.

Answer (score 1):

IF commercial libraries are ok for you then I can recommend [SecureBlackBox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/) (not affilliated, just a happy customer).

Comment: @MixedCoder they offer a license including source... OR do you mean free ?

Comment: yeah for free, it's for like $724.00 <.<

Comment: @MixedCoder ok, so a free and opensource .NET library better than BountyCastle (maybe you should update the question to reflect that) - sorry, but I don't know such a library... I hope that someone else can give you a better answer.